# Синхронизация локального и удаленного репозиториев gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket, репозиторий

Есть gitlab c приватными репозиториями которые установили на сервере. 
Есть локальный репозиторий (gitkraken gui) который теперь после перехода на удаленку недоступен (нет доступа к той сети). Но есть доступ по RDP к моему рабочему компьютеру где есть доступ к этой сети.  Можно ли как то синхронизировать репозитории  чтобы не приходилось кидать git патчи туда сюда?

Comment: Настройте нормальные ssh туннели

Answer (score 0):

Если удаленная система Windows, то можно предложить следующее:

В свойствах RDP указываете "пробрасывать локальные диски на удаленный компьютер"

Например ваш проект лежит локально в папке `D:\myproject` тогда на удаленном компьютере в PowerShell:

```
cd '\\tsclient\D\myproject'
git commit -m "Remote commit"
git push
```

Comment: Нет, mac os(домашний ноут) соединяется по RDP через шлюз с windows server 2012, а оттуда уже через RDP к ubuntu.

Comment: @manking как все запутано))) а порты только рдп открыты?

Comment: теоретически и в маке рдп должен пробрасывать локальные shared foldrs. Надо подробней изучить вопрос

Comment: Да там есть проброс папок. Но этот подход лучше чем создать еще один удаленный репозиторий?

Comment: если есть способ вывести гитлаб в глобальную сеть, то лучше в глобальную сеть и пользоваться репозиторием. мой ответ относился не к созданию нового репозитория, а к клонированию приватного репозитория в вашу локальную папку через проброс. чтобы можно было комитить изменения в приватный. поговорити с админами. может есть возможность через впн войти в офисную сеть, чтобы так не заморачиваться

Comment: Нет как раз через VPN и нельзя.